# Как отправить письмо по smtp используя Zend Framework2?

Tags: php, doctrine2, zend2

Как отправить письмо  по smtp используя Zend Framework и ORM Doctrine,а так же в использовании локальный сервер  OpenServer?
Все библиотеки и классы подключены.Данный метод приложения используется по видеоуроку автором https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcREJw815NM&list=PLoonZ8wII66j76OU66nzKdKy1kYp0fWK0&index=48.
Там ответа на вопрос не получил,надеюсь здесь найду ответ на решение.

Регистрация,работает, как только добавил метод для отправки письма, после регистрации получаю ошибку.

Метод отвечающий за отправку письма:

```
    protected function sendConfirmationEmail($user)
    {
        $transport = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('mail.transport');
        $message = new Message();
        $message->setEncoding("UTF-8");
        $message->addTo($user->getUsrEmail())
            ->addFrom('my_email')
            ->setSubject('Регистрация')
            ->setBody('Вы успешно зарегистрированы на ' . $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_HOST'));

        $transport->send($message);
    }
```

В модуле,в методе прописана фабрика по производству 'mail_transport :

```
  'mail.transport' => function(ServiceManager $serviceManager){
            $config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
            $transport = new Smtp();
            $transport->setOptions(new SmtpOptions($config['mail']['transport']['options']));
            return $transport;
        },
```

В файле сconfig\autoload\mail.lcal.php  прописаны настройки отправки:

```
<?php
return array(
    'mail' => array(
        'transport' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
      
                'connection_class' => 'plain',
                'connection_config' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'ssl' => 'tls',
                ),

            ),
        ),
```

Собственно сама ошибка:

> File:
> D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol.php:351
> Message:
> 5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
> 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v7sm1368745ljk.7 - gsmtp Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Plain.php(81):
>
> Zend\Mail\Protocol\AbstractProtocol->_expect(235)
>
> ## 1 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp.php(193):
>
> Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Plain->auth()
>
> ## 2 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(340):
>
> Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp->helo('localhost')
>
> ## 3 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(325):
>
> Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->connect()
>
> ## 4 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(336):
>
> Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->lazyLoadConnection()
>
> ## 5 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(205):
>
> Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->connect()
>
> ## 6 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\module\AuthDoctrine\src\AuthDoctrine\Controller\IndexController.php(146):
>
> Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp->send(Object(Zend\Mail\Message))
>
> ## 7 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\module\AuthDoctrine\src\AuthDoctrine\Controller\IndexController.php(125):
>
> AuthDoctrine\Controller\IndexController->sendConfirmationEmail(Object(Blog\Entity\User))
>
> ## 8 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83):
>
> AuthDoctrine\Controller\IndexController->registerAction()
>
> ## 9 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\BaseController.php(18):
>
> Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 10 [internal function]: Application\Controller\BaseController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 11 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468):
>
> call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 12 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207):
>
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch',
> Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> ## 13 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117):
>
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch',
> Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> ## 14 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114):
>
> Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request),
> Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
>
> ## 15 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 16 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468):
>
> call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> ## 17 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207):
>
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch',
> Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> ## 18 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(316):
>
> Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch',
> Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> ## 19 D:\OSPanel\domains\zblogprofessional.local\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()

Comment: Укажите верные логин и пароль (не тут, а в вашем коде)

Comment: Да,я вижу, но логин и пароль к моей почте правильный. Единственное что я не совсем понял, нужно ли в опенсервере  прописывать настройки для  Smtp?  Как то прописывал, но всеравно ту же ошибку выдавало.Опечаток не было, т.к. я логинился в  gmail под теми же данными.

Comment: возможно  gmail блокирует отправку :\

Comment: Решил ошибку .Нужно было открыть доступ не безопасным приложениям в настройках аккаунта Gmail.